# how to set a variable that is shared between multiple controllers

Tags: sapui5

Is it a good idea to set a js file(in util folder) which return a global object which will keep a list of different map of variables .
So in the index.js I can pass the app variable and followed by accessing it from controller.

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/base/ManagedObject"], function (ManagedObject) {
  "use strict";
  let globals = {};
  return globals;
});
```

and in index.js

```
sap.ui.define(
  [
    "sap/ui/base/ManagedObject",
    "zap/util/globals",
  ],
  function (ManagedObject,  globals) {
    "use strict";
  let oApp = new sap.m.App();
  globals.oApp = oApp;
  });
```

and in controller event handler

```
sap.ui.define(
  ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "zap/util/globals"],
  function (Controller, globals) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("zap.controller.Master", {
      onListPress: function (oEvt) {
        let oApp = globals.oApp;
       }
});
});
```

Comment: No, I'd use a JSON model. For complex objects, use the define/require functions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model, and load it in the manifest.json, so it would be accessible from each part of your application.

```
{
    "models": {
        "globalModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "Models/GlobalModel.json"
        }
    }
}`
```